# Remote Access to MySql DB (Hosting Options)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am currently writing a script in Python which uploads data to a localhost MySql DB. I am now looking to relocate this MySql DB to a remote server with a static IP address. I have a web hosting facility but this only allows clients to connect to the MySql DB if I specify the domain / IP address from which clients will connect. My Python script will be ran on a number of computers that will connect via a mobile broadband dongle and therefore, the IP addresses will vary on a day-to-day basis as the IP address is allocated dynamically.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue either with my web hosting facility (cPanel) or alternatively, any suggestions on MySql hosting services that allow remote access from any IP addresses (assuming they successfully authenticate with passwords etc...) Would SSH possibly address this and allow me to transmit data?

Comment: Why wouldn't your Python script connect to a server that then connects to MySQL? It's not a good idea to let any IP talk to the database.

Comment: I agree with you, is not secure, but if the server which connect to mysql change IP dynamic, you need to allow all IPs, or manualy update  IP on every change.

Comment: What kind of server is it if it changes its IP? Hosted on a home connection?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Cpanel and add the wildcard `%` on remote Mysql Connection options (cPanel > Remote MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you is to get a dynamic dns address from a vendor for your laptop.  Basically, you install a little piece of software that updates the foreign system with your current IP.  You can then use a domain name rather than an IP in your mysql user access, and the server will do the domain name lookup and grant you access, without you having to open up your mysql server to connections from every server on the planet, as you would be doing based on Gabriel's solution.  Dyndns is one company that offers this service.

You could also use ssh and tunnel your sessions.  You simply would have to setup your local client to do port forwarding for the 3306 port, set up your ssh connnection, and connect to localhost and your script will act as if it is connecting locally.  Although a little bit more complicated to setup, and less transparent, it is a really great work around.  Assuming command line ssh client:

```
ssh -L 3306:domain_or_ip_mysqlserver:3306 username@mysqlserver

mysql -u username -p -h localhost databasename
```

Answer (score 0):

As gview said, I dynamic DNS service is a possible solution. DynDns will work great but a more affordable solution is [ZoneEdit.com](http://zoneedit.com). I use ZoneEdit to handle multiple domains hosted on a Windows Server box with a dynamic IP (cable modem). I have a Windows service that constantly polls for an IP address change. When the service detects a change, it notifies ZoneEdit. ZoneEdit then redirects requests to the new IP.